# Problem with comparing numerical values while column-wise parsing CSV file

Tags: bash

I have a CSV file with the following columns:

```
Year,113 Cause Name,Cause Name,State,Deaths,Age-adjusted Death Rate
```

These are a few sample lines from the file:

```
2016,Malignant neoplasms (C00-C97),Cancer,Missouri,12696,167
2015,Malignant neoplasms (C00-C97),Cancer,Missouri,12965,173.4
2014,Malignant neoplasms (C00-C97),Cancer,Missouri,13067,177.7
2013,Malignant neoplasms (C00-C97),Cancer,Missouri,12955,179.4
2012,Malignant neoplasms (C00-C97),Cancer,Missouri,12919,182.3
```

I am trying to build a CSV parser in Bash that will take arguments from the user and display the rows that match with the arguments. This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

# set up the arguments
for i in "$@"
do
case $i in
    -y=*|--year=*)
    YEAR="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -c=*|--cause=*)
    CAUSE="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -s=*|--state=*)
    STATE="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -d=*|--deaths=*)
    DEATHS="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    -ad=*|--age_adjusted=*)
    AGE_ADJUSTED="${i#*=}"
    shift # past argument=value
    ;;
    *)
          # unknown option
    ;;
esac
done

# print out the values of the passed arguments
echo $YEAR
echo $CAUSE
echo $STATE
echo $DEATHS
echo $AGE_ADJUSTED

# read the file, segregating value in each column
while IFS='' read -r year cause1 cause2 state deaths age_adj; do
    if [ -z "$DEATHS" ]; then                       # user did not pass a "number of deaths" argument
        if [ -z "$AGE_ADJUSTED" ]; then             # user also did not pass an age "adjusted death rate" argument
            echo "$year $cause1 $cause2 $state $deaths $age_adj" | grep "$YEAR" | grep "$CAUSE" | grep "$STATE"
        else                                        # user passed an age "adjusted death rate" argument, check against that value
            if [[ $age_adj -ge $AGE_ADJUSTED ]]; then
                echo "$year $cause1 $cause2 $state $deaths $age_adj" | grep "$YEAR" | grep "$CAUSE" | grep "$STATE"
            fi
        fi
    else                                            # user passed a "number of deaths" argument
        if [ -z "$AGE_ADJUSTED" ]; then             # user did not pass an "age adjusted death rate" argument
            echo "$year $cause1 $cause2 $state $deaths $age_adj" | grep "$YEAR" | grep "$CAUSE" | grep "$STATE"
        else                                        # user passed both "number of deaths" and "age adjusted death rate" arguments         
            if [[ $deaths -ge $DEATHS &&  $age_adj -ge $AGE_ADJUSTED ]]; then
                echo "$year $cause1 $cause2 $state $deaths $age_adj" | grep "$YEAR" | grep "$CAUSE" | grep "$STATE"
            fi
        fi
    fi    
done < "$1"
```

The problem happens when I try to compare either the number of deaths column ($deaths) against the passed argument value ($DEATHS) and the Age Adjusted Death Rate column ($age_adj) against the passed argument value ($AGE_ADJUSTED). It doesn't fire the comparison, rather prints out every result that matches with the other arguments (if passed).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am passing the arguments in the following format:

```
./main.sh -y=2015 -d=50000 <additional arguments if I want to> ./file.csv
```

Comment: At the very least, you will need to say `while IFS=','`, not `while IFS=''`.

Comment: Why you merge every columns into a string and grep in it although you have once separated them? You better to perform column-wise comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`.

```
YEAR="2015"
CAUSE=""
STATE=""
DEATHS=""
AGE_ADJUSTED=""

awk \
    -vFS=, -vOFS=, \
    -vYEAR=$YEAR \
    -vCAUSE=$CAUSE \
    -vSTATE=$STATE \
    -vDEATHS=$DEATHS \
    -vAGE_ADJUSTED=$AGE_ADJUSTED \
'{
    if (length(YEAR) != 0) {
        if ($1 != YEAR) {
            next;
        }
    }
    if (length(CAUSE) != 0) {
        if ($2 != CAUSE) {
            next;
        }
    }
    if (length(STATE) != 0) {
        if ($3 != STATE) {
            next;
        }
    }
    if (length(DEATHS) != 0) {
        if ($4 != DEATHS) {
            next;
        }
    }
    if (length(AGE_ADJUSTED) != 0) {
        if ($5 != AGE_ADJUSTED) {
            next;
        }
    }
    print
}' file.csv
```

Live version available at [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/1XbNNa).

1. I think the awk script is pretty straightforward. If the variable length is nonzero then check if the column from the file matches the variable value. If it doesn't go to the `next` line. If all matches match or are zeros, then `print` current line.
2. `-vVAR=VAL` sets internal `awk` variables. `-vFS=,` and `-vOFS=,` set output and input separators for `awk`.
3. `-y=*|--year=*)` - for portability and readability reason I suggest you follow [POSIX utility conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) and/or [GNU argument syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html). Just use GNUs [getopt](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) (I prefer it) or BASHs `getopts` (widely available, but does not support long arguments).
4. `for i in "$@"; do .... shift; ...` The shift does not affect for parameters. Once they are read-up by for, you can't change them. So the `shift`s are usuless there, and do nothing. I prefer using `while (($#)); do .... shift; done;` or just `for i; do ... done`
5. `while IFS='' read -r`  is commonly used to read a line *without splitting*. The `IFS` variable controls over which variables the `read` command will split the line. `read` reads data from input until a separator specified with `-d` is read, default newline, then splits it using any of the characters found in `IFS`. You meant to `while IFS=, read -r ...`

Comment: Nvm about the previous comments, I figured it out what I was doing wrong. Ty for the help!